# Is it mandatory to have only one DBHelper class for an application or can we have more than one DBHelper clasess?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

In my application, I want use two different DBHelper classes for working on two different tables.
Is it possible to have more than one DBhelper classes in my app?

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened?

Comment: You cannot have two classes named `DBHelper` in the same Java package, though you can have them in separate packages. You should not have more than one `SQLiteOpenHelper` per database, if your proposed `DBHelper` is a subclass of `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

Comment: I experienced that you should only have one dbhelper per database. So for you, with 2 tables in one db , no, i wouldnt recommend to have more than once. I tried it once with more than one and it gave me more disadvantages to handle all the interactions than with one. To be clear: It is possible for sure, but i don't recommend

Comment: You simply **don't need** to have a distinct class for each table.

Comment: i tried it, but table not found exceptions are raised. only one table is creating, so the exception is raised for the other table @nhouser9

Comment: thank you @CommonsWare. you cleared my doubts by " You should not have more than one SQLiteOpenHelper per database, if your proposed DBHelper is a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper". im not using two classes with same names. thank you so much.

Comment: You need to use proper versioning: [When is SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate() / onUpgrade() run?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run)